# PHP Mysql query array assigned to variable and used in another array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to use an array gathered from a mysql query as a variable.  I want this variable to be used in another array.  Code below.

```
$sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Username SEPARATOR ', ') AS Username FROM manage";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $test[] = $row["Username"];      
}    
// Grab Random User From Array    
$a = [user1, user2, user3];
$buyer = $a[mt_rand(0, count($a) - 1)];    
echo $buyer;
```

The above code displays one random user.

Now, I want to take the `$test[]` array and populate the `$a` array to accomplish the same thing!

Like this:

```
$a = [$test];
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

thanks
marc

Comment: What does GROUP_CONCAT do if you haven't grouped by anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using `GROUP_CONCAT` in your query, as it will put all the usernames into one string. There's also no need to use an intermediary variable (`$test`), you can store the usernames directly into `$a`. Finally, [`shuffle`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) is a better way to get a random value from an array. Try this instead:

```
$sql = "SELECT Username FROM manage";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $a[] = $row["Username"];      
}    
// Grab Random User From Array   
shuffle($a); 
$buyer = $a[0];
echo $buyer;
```